# Calculate next Net value based on the preceding rolling Net Values

Tags: sql

I have a scenario where I need to calculate Amounts based on a number of deductions, but after each deduction the next deduction is calculated on the rolling Net of the previous Deductions.

So,

Gross Amount * Deduction 1 = Deduction Amount 1

1. Gross Amount – Deduction 1 = Net Amount 1

Then in order of sequence that the further Deductions are recorded: -

Net Amount 1 * Deduction 2 for Deduction Amount 2

2. Net Amount 1 – (Net Amount 1 * Net Deduction 1) = Net Amount 2

Net Amount 2 * Net Deduction 2 = Deduction 2

3. Net Amount 2 – (Net Amount 2 * Net Deduction 2) = Net Amount 3

Net Amount 3 * Net Deduction 3 = Deduction 3

4. Net Amount 3 - (Net Amount 3 * Net Deduction 3) = Net Amount 4

So, each Net Deduction is based on the Net Amount result from the previous Net Deduction.

If that makes sense?

A table of values
[image]

I have tried so far using Lag and Last_Value, but they literally only pick the last Row and I'm stumped as to how to get the rolling Net Values as it were.

Any suggestions greatly received.

Regards,

NJC

Comment: One method is probably just a recursive CTE along the lines of https://dbfiddle.uk/_89Eywhm . Possibly there's a better way with window functions, but this was the first thing I thought of.